# XSLT: Creating array from parameters and checking for null values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Basically there is a list of necessary parameters being created by a fellow developer using PHP. He is passing those into my XSLT and I need to create a "check" to make sure each one is populated.

Is there a way to create an array of these params and loop through them instead of creating IF statement for every single one?

The params are:

```
     <xsl:param name="enviroment_url_prefix"/>
     <xsl:param name="display_layout" />
     <xsl:param name="content_title" />
     <xsl:param name="content_descr" />
     <xsl:param name="num_comments" />
     <xsl:param name="num_items" />
     <xsl:param name="display_theme" />
     <xsl:param name="is_web"  />
     <xsl:param name="is_trial"  />
     <xsl:param name="img_width" />
     <xsl:param name="image_width" />
     <xsl:param name="time_ago" />
```

My Check statment looks something like this:

```
      <xsl:if test="$current_param=''">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">
          $current_param is empty
        </xsl:message>
      </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop over parameter *names* would require dynamic evaluation, which is not supported by XSLT. You could invoke a for-each over parameter *elements* (`document('')/*/xsl:param`), but that would still not give you the run-time value of each parameter.

You cannot do these checks from within your stylesheet in any other way than hard-coding them individually.

---

As an idea, you *could* use a single XML document as input for your XSLT program, instead of a list of parameters.

Build an XML file like this (or let your fellow programmer create it in the first place):

```
<params>
  <param name="enviroment_url_prefix" value="{whatever value came from PHP}" />
  <!-- ... -->
</params>
```

and pass that to your main XSLT stylesheet as its sole `<xsl:param name="input" />` - not as a string, but as an actual document object.

If that's not possible for some reason, let your fellow programmer provide a URL where this XML document can be loaded and use:

```
<xsl:variable name="input" select="document($params_url)" />
<xsl:variable name="p" select="$input/params/param" />
```

Now you have an actual tree that you can inspect:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$p[@value = '']">
  <xsl:message terminate="yes">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, ' is empty')" />
  </xsl:message>
</xsl:if>
```

and use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$p[@name='enviroment_url_prefix']" />
```

That being said, in the end it might be a lot easier to do input validation on the PHP side.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a great idea! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me run through it. Good Stuff.